# How do I save a workbook using xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I have an excel worksheet, some buttons and some macros. I use xlwings to make it work. Is there a way to save the workbook through xlwings ? I want to extract a specific sheet after doing an operation, but the saved sheet is the extracted sheet before the operation without the generated data.

My code for extracting the sheet I need is the following:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
sheet_name = Wscript.Arguments.Item(1)
dir_name = Wscript.Arguments.Item(2)
file_name = Wscript.Arguments.Item(3)

Dim objExcel
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False

Dim objWorkbook
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks(src_file)

objWorkbook.Sheets(sheet_name).Copy
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs dir_name + file_name + ".xlsx", 51
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs dir_name + file_name + ".csv", 6

objWorkbook.Close False
objExcel.Quit
```

Comment: Workbook.save() should make it into the next release...https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/110

Answer (score 13):

`Book.save()` has now been implemented: see the [docs](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/api/book.html#xlwings.Book.save).