# How do I create an excel file with an existing macro using Python?

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I created a macro using VBA and I want generate an excel file from python that is macro-enabled and has a button with this macro

xlwings

Comment: Why don't you just copy that file using `xlwings` and then manipulate accordingly. That will retain your Macro and buttons.

Comment: See Here on how to [save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27281914/how-do-i-save-a-workbook-using-xlwings) a Workbook using `Xlwings`